# Trying to get a handle on displaying an image with zoom and pan

Tags: android, android-imageview

I've read a ton of posts, and tried a few of the suggested solutions, but not having much luck.

I have a ViewPager which is happily displaying text views.

I now want to enhance it to also support ImageViews. The images may be in a wide variety of shapes and sizes, so I need to give the user the ability to zoom and pan in order to focus on any area.

NB. I do not necessarily want pinch zoom, as the pinch-zoom libraries I've tried (eg. https://github.com/jasonpolites/gesture-imageview/blob/master/main/src/com/polites/android/GestureImageView.java and http://blog.sephiroth.it/2011/04/04/imageview-zoom-and-scroll/) seem to work intermittently, and crash with out-of-memory. So rather than complicate the solution with gesture detection, I'm happy to put a slider control above the view to achieve the zoom UI.

I'm struggling to get a handle on what is an appropriate view hierarchy to achieve this (eg. do I need a ScrollView or is panning a feature within the ImageView), and should I be scaling the bitmap, or resizing the view?

Any suggestions on what view components I need to use would be much appreciated.

Should I even be using ImageView? I've seen some answers suggesting that a WebView is a better starting point.

My instinct is that what I'm trying to do should be pretty basic, and require no more than the right view hierarchy and view config settings. It seems too simple to require a custom ImageView class, but of course I might be wrong.

Comment: try this: https://github.com/pskink/ZoomView

Comment: @pslink, many thanks for the link,and I'm sure it would work. However I'm trying to avoid third part code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Should I even be using ImageView? I've seen some answers suggesting that a WebView is a better starting point.**

This is the way I solved it in the end. I simply wrapped the image filename in some HTML and gave it to a webview.

This gave me the following specific benefits:-

- The detailed user behaviour (eg. zoom rate, pinch sensitivity, availability of an on screen control) were consistent with the browser, and so familiar to the user's muscle memory
- I don't need to depend on any third party code
- Since it's core Android, it's probably better tested against edge cases (eg. one library I considered didn't support landscape)
- I don't need to worry about out of memory situations with Bitmap processing
- In the future, I might want to provide "web page" as one of the items in my ViewPager anyway, so one stone, two birds.

Here is the code I ended up with.

```
File imgFile = new  File(FILESDIR,FILENAME);
if(imgFile.exists()){
  WebView wv = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
  wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
  wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
  String html = ("<html><img src='"+imgFile.getName()+"'></html>" );
  wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("file://"+imgFile.getAbsolutePath(),
    html,
    "text/html",
    "utf-8",
  "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use GestureDetectors. Google has excellent sample interactiveChart for this, see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/training/InteractiveChart and http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html